# Doxygen: how to display a function declaration INLINED into a markdown page (without \ref)

Tags: c#, markdown, doxygen

On the documentation for each class, we can see a list of function. These functions are presented each with a nice HTML template which includes the name, arguments, return value, etc.

In our project we have manuals for various systems written in Markdown, and we wish to make reference to certain important API functions. Currently I can only find \ref but this makes for pretty bad UX, readers will be jumping around constantly to browse the definition. There is also no mouse hover bubble with the declaration details.

I have done a lot of searching all over the internet and even ChatGPT believes this is not possible. I must be missing something, I thought Doxygen was industry standard.

Cheers

Comment: This question has been cross posted to https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/10370 and there a comment is given as well.